# How to delete .git repository on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, git

I have been using **git** on **windows 8.1**, Whenever I try to remove a git repository completely using following command

```
rm -rf .git
```

I got following an errors:

```
rm: cannot unlink `.git/objects/pack/pack-1d2a33e057e25d7deb538366e3ef14c91a9551c8.pack': Permission
 denied
rm: cannot unlink `.git/objects/pack/pack-34012f955a1f523f6d828416f8076a1ef0b7f6da.pack': Permission
 denied
rm: cannot unlink `.git/objects/pack/pack-34a1ab8c950bba63f59a3e9fac66c81de3891052.pack': Permission
 denied
rm: cannot unlink `.git/objects/pack/pack-4d509a81a88109118ed881a5f8bd8ef333f2a773.pack': Permission
 denied
rm: cannot unlink `.git/objects/pack/pack-60e2cc3727a15201698236a201b7a75b45dab190.pack': Permission
 denied
rm: cannot unlink `.git/objects/pack/pack-676f92fd1e3e0f25fcc68850a7cbc2f50cab388e.pack': Permission
 denied
rm: cannot unlink `.git/objects/pack/pack-a71fc7d3a49a47d2ce1b89193bfc461b24727021.pack': Permission
 denied
rm: cannot unlink `.git/objects/pack/pack-b105d1108006ac851715ff7d7e18f39ffbf5c978.pack': Permission
 denied
rm: cannot unlink `.git/objects/pack/pack-b9a22b325fd18860ad1cf3974ea082a1037a085c.pack': Permission
 denied
rm: cannot unlink `.git/objects/pack/pack-c26f6794a158c7b057a0612fa3f578964721133e.pack': Permission
 denied
rm: cannot unlink `.git/objects/pack/pack-d7653161024d3ff938b409c7993adf7a12811102.pack': Permission
 denied
rm: cannot unlink `.git/objects/pack/pack-ee4637aea5cbe84947dd388fa8a0eac72cd4760a.pack': Permission
 denied
rm: cannot unlink `.git/objects/pack/pack-fd00786f2b5407f67aaed53e69a08ed3a807551e.pack': Permission
 denied
rm: cannot remove directory `.git/objects/pack': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove directory `.git/objects': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove directory `.git': Directory not empty
```

Also, I gives permission using following command, but getting same issue.

```
chmod 777 .git
```

How can I solve? please help me?

Comment: Do you have permissions on file/folders? Try to remove it from explorer of from an administrative console.

Answer (score 2):

As an admin in windows cmd on the right folder :

`RMDIR /S /Q .git`

Comment: I got an error : .git\objects\pack\pack-1d2a33e057e25d7deb538366e3ef14c91a9551c8.pack - The process cannot access the
 file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Stop all git application (TortoiseGit, SourceTree, ...) that may still run and access your git repository.